# Optimizing webpack builds for libraries

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I am working on a library that can be used both by Node.js and in browsers. The library is written in typescript.

This library has a browser build, using webpack. When Webpack is used, several files are overridden. One example is that it will use a browser-based Base64 API, instead of using Node.js buffers, which greatly reduces the library size.

This is a portion of my webpack configuration that makes this work:

```
resolve: {
  extensions: ['.web.ts', '.web.js', '.ts', '.js', '.json'],
  alias: {
    // We need an alternative 'querystring', because the default is not
    // 100% compatible
    querystring: 'querystring-browser'
  }
},
```

What this allows is that I have these 2 files:

```
base64.js
base64.web.js
```

By default the first base64 will be used, but webpack will prefer the `.web.js` file.

This works great.

The issue I have is that many users don't download the browser build, and add it manually to their script tag. It's very common for the library to be included as an npm dependency, and the end-user is responsible for running Webpack and create a larger bundle of all their dependencies.

In that case I don't have control over webpack configuration, but I want these users to still benefit from these optimizations. The difference for my library is significant (several hundred kb's).

Is there a way to get the webpack ran by users that included by library is a dependency to use the smaller browser-based versions of my API?

Comment: Not what you were asking for (sorry about that), but what I would do in your situation: - detect the runtime environment
- based on the runtime environment either throw an exception or log a warning (depends of how strict you'd like to be) if the wrong version is used. React for example logs warnings if non-production react builds are used in production.

Answer (score 0):

You can point your `main` field in `package.json` as usual at the one targeted at node usage, but you can also specify `browser` field that webpack would use for the entry point for browser environment. If you don't have too many dependencies of your library, just bundle it for web yourself and specify that output file in `browser` field